# MS Access 2003 - Opening a report without it printing

Tags: ms-access, vba, report, ms-access-2003

I used

```
Docmd.OpenReport "Report1"
```

from another form and it seems to just want to print the report without actually displaying it. I want to display the report, not print it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the acView argument to acViewPreview:

```
docmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview
```

Access Help says you can use one of these AcView constants:

```
acViewDesign 
acViewNormal 
acViewPreview
```

**acViewNormal** is the default and prints the report immediately.

Comment: `acViewReport` is the correct one to use for newer version of Access, as it opens the Report in the normal view. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acview

Comment: So does that print the report?